# What is a wise way to deal with a student of this type?

Tags: tutoring

This question is inspired by some real-life experiences. I came across two or so private tutoring teenager students that give me a feeling that they did not pay enough attention to the contents and instead constantly unjustly judged me in mind. For instance, one of them was self-righteous such that he was always like you-say-yours-I-do-mine and he never showed some outstanding, impressive ability by which my anger would be alleviated. For now I cannot provide a specific example of how this lead me to think he was a judging student (it seems too difficult for me to describe literally); but let us consider the case if he was. It took me nearly a year to reach a temporary conclusion against his behavior. What annoyed me is that such a student ignores his own lack of knowledge or thinking quality and focuses on judging his teacher.  In fact, I guess I am an "introspector", meaning I introspect myself on a regular basis. For the matter under consideration, I looked inside and felt that in such a case my annoyedness does not come from my insecurity, if any; and it cannot even be from my quality of "preaching" (this is not a statement of pride.). In passing, a useful fact would be that overall my students were respectful and more than satisfied with my tutoring; many of them still keep me posted.

So I would love to know a wise way to handle a student of the type, i.e. a student such that his understanding of the subject is below-average and he judges his teacher, without being annoyed. I am after a generic answer such that it applies to most "sane" people; it need not be specifically for me, and hence my detailed personality information may not be needed in order to post an answer.

Comment: I've cleared most of the comments. Please take further discussion to either [chat] or [meta], as appropriate. Further comments on this question will likely be deleted.

Comment: @YngwieMalmsteen - Sure, but please take the advice to heart. People here are trying to assist and are giving good feedback.

Answer (score 6):

Do not try to take any action based on your assessment of the student's attitude. Such judgements are very error prone, and impossible to prove.

Instead, focus on actual behavior and outcomes. For example, if you set some exercise such as writing an essay on a given topic, does it get done on time and to an appropriate standard? Is the student's work improving?

If those things are happening, there is no problem. Just carry on.

If they are not happening, first discuss the lack of work/progress with the student. If that does not result in improvement, and a third party such as a parent is paying you, also discuss it with them.